# how o change background color of html using javascript in chrome console

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Change color</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    <h1>MY Name SAIRAM</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my output:

[image: Output of html file]

Now what I am trying to do is change the background color of the HTML in the Chrome console and code is:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var isBlue = false;
setInterval(function () {
  if (isBlue) {
    body.style.backgroung="white";
  } else {
    body.style.background="blue";
  }

  isBlue = !isBlue; 
}, 1000);
```

the output should change the background color of the page every second but it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps, beacause you write backgroung instead of background ?

Comment: backgroung is misspelled.
Hopefully you will not apply this logic with such colors to real site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you just spelling of `background` is not correct.

it should be `body.style.background="white";` Not `body.style.backgroung="white";`

```js
var body=document.querySelector("body");
var isBlue=false;
setInterval(function(){
if(isBlue)
{
    body.style.background="white";
}
else
{
    body.style.background="blue";
}
isBlue = !isBlue;

},1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>change color</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">FaceBook</a>
<h1>MY Name SAIRAM</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the name background is not correct you have used like this

body.style.backgroung="white";

please correct it ,it will work